# Обособляется ли деепричастный оборот?

Tags: пунктуация

Здравствуйте.

Из одного спортивного издания:

**Я зарабатываю на жизнь, нокаутируя других людей.**

Разве тут можно отделить оборот от сказуемого?Обособляется оборот или нет?Как это определить?

Answer (score 1):

Розенталь:

> *Деепричастный оборот, как правило, обособляется независимо от места, занимаемого им по отношению к глаголу-сказуемому... 
>   Деепричастный
>   оборот не обособляется: 1) если оборот (обычно со значением
>   обстоятельства образа действия) тесно связан по содержанию со
>   сказуемым и образует смысловой центр высказывания...*

[https://orfogrammka.ru/пунктуация/обособление_деепричастного_оборота/](https://orfogrammka.ru/%D0%BF%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%82%D1%83%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F/%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%B5%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE_%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B0/)

В нашем случае деепричастный оборот не сводится к обстоятельству образа действия (ср. "Я зарабатываю на жизнь не вставая с дивана"), поэтому запятая нужна.

Answer (score 1):

**Я зарабатываю на жизнь, нокаутируя других людей.**

1) Деепричастный оборот обособляется, так как деепричастие обозначает добавочное действие, а не признак основного действия.

2) Предложение без деепричастного оборота по смыслу **самодостаточно**, например: Я не сижу дома, у меня нет для этого средств. Я зарабатываю на жизнь.

Другое дело, что оно обычно **включается в другие синтаксические конструкции или дополняется второстепенным членом**, чтобы выразить какое-то сообщение в законченном виде: Я зарабатываю на жизнь **боксом.** Я зарабатываю на жизнь, **когда занимаюсь боксом.**

Ведь никого не удивляет,что мы обособляем придаточное предложение.

**Примечание**

**Существуют парные варианты**, когда сложно определить синтаксическую роль **обычно одиночного деепричастия** (на обособление деепричастий может оказать влияние их позиция), например:  На солнышке Полкан с Барбосом, **лёжа**, грелись (= лежали и грелись). После обеда ложились отдохнуть, но не засыпали, а разговаривали  **лёжа**.

Меняя позицию деепричастия, **автор** уточняет свою мысль.